# How to use CASE Statement for Multiple Select Statements in SQL

Tags: sql, database, select, case

i have 3 Tables named as `Vendor`, `Customers` and `ReceivePayment`. in my `ReceivePayment` Table i have column named `PaymentType` and `AccountID`. all i want is to Select data from Vendor or customer table by using `AccountID` in `ReceivePayment` table but i have to apply condition either select data from Customer table or vendor table and condition will be based on `PaymentType` column of `ReceivePayment` table. like if i have 'Sale' in `PaymentType` column then it should select data from Customers table or if i have 'Purchase' in PaymentType column then it should select data from Vendor table.

I am using case statement but i don't know how to use Select statement in THEN Clause of case statement.

[image: Screenshot of ReceivePayment Table]

i am trying to use this code

```
    SELECT CASE ReceivePayment.PaymentType

    WHEN  'Sale' THEN SELECT Name FROM Vendor WHERE VendorID = ReceivePayment.AccountID
    WHEN  'Purchase' THEN SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE CustID = ReceivePayment.AccountID
END
FROM ReceivePayment
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the query that you have attempted (perhaps simplified to focus on the point you are having trouble with).  As written, the question makes little sense to other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close:

```
SELECT (CASE rp.PaymentType
            WHEN  'Sale'
            THEN (SELECT v.Name FROM Vendor v WHERE v.VendorID = rp.AccountID)
            WHEN  'Purchase'
            THEN (SELECT c.Name FROM Customers c WHERE c.CustID = rp.AccountID)
        END)
FROM ReceivePayment rp;
```

You just need parentheses around the subqueries.  Note:  You need to be sure that the subqueries only return 0 or 1 row, or you will get an error.

Note that I also added table aliases to simplify the query.

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoof, i was not sure that i am just missing braces around my select statement :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use conditional join and `COALESCE` something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(v.Name, C.Name, '') AS Name
FROM ReceivePayment AS rp
LEFT JOIN Vendor AS v ON rp.AccountID = v.VendorID AND rp.PaymentType = 'Sale'
LEFT JOIN Customers AS c ON rp.AccountID = c.CustID AND rp.PaymentType = 'Purchase'
```